2-argument combinators and Turing completeness
SK, BCKW, and BAMT combinator systems are known to be Turing-complete and convertible into each other. (BAMT is mentioned in this blog post)
Sxyz ~> xz(yz)
Kxy  ~> x

Bxyz ~> x(yz)
Cxyz ~> xzy
Kxy  ~> x
Wxy  ~> xyy

Bxyz ~> x(yz)
Axy  ~> y
Mx   ~> xx
Txy  ~> yx

Here, B, C, and S take three arguments.
Interestingly, the fixed point combinator can be expressed using only two-argument combinators:
Y' = (\xy. xyx) (\yx. y(xyx))
Theta = (\xy. y(xxy)) (\xy. y(xxy))

My question is: Is there any Turing-complete basis that only consists of one- or two-argument combinators? More specifically, is it possible to construct B or S with such combinators?

It is known such two-variable combinators don't form the complete basis (MathOverflow question, Statman R. "Two variables are not enough"). This page lists computability of the word problem as an open problem as of 2014.

@pcpthm shouldn't you comment be an answer?

Thanks for bringing up BAMT, deriving BCKW from it was fun!
